# Pass array number of object to event handler

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of PictureBoxes.

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{ 
   this.elevatorDoors[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
}
```

I would like to pass to the click event of one object,the array number that the particular object has.

```
this.elevatorDoors[i].Click +=
      new System.EventHandler((sender,e)=>this.elevatorDoor_Click(sender,e, i));
```

But all I get when the event fires up is the number 10. I would like to get for example the number 4 when I click on the 4th PictureBox.

Comment: Let me know if this isn't a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710655/multiple-control-click-events-handled-by-one-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tempValue = i;
this.elevatorDoors[i].Click +=
      new System.EventHandler((sender,e)=> this.elevatorDoor_Click(sender,e, tempValue));
```

This will fix it. So you must pretty much ensure that when you are Invoking the event you are taking the current value of your loop iteration. After leaving the loop the value will always equal to last value. So you introduce tempValue which stores the current iteration.

Comment: It gives me 10 again

Comment: @AnastasiosPapanikolaou okay this should fix it, define temp which takes the current iteration value and give it to EventHandler.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is more like a local scope problem. Just create a new function where you assign the clickhandler

```
private void AssignCallback(PictureBox pb, int index) {
    pb.Click += new System.EventHandler((sender,e)=>this.elevatorDoor_Click(sender,e, index));
}
```

An alternative method would be to use the `Tag` property on the picturebox and read the value of the tag in your callback like so

```
this.elevatorDoors[i].Tag = i;
this.elevatorDoors[i].Click +=
  new System.EventHandler((sender,e)=>this.elevatorDoor_Click(sender,e, Convert.ToInt32(((Control)i).Tag))-;
```